# How to export / import funnel reports in Admin API for GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-api

i need to setup 100 funnel reports for GA4 on testing and production enviroment (separate properties). Is there a way how to use Admin API to import / export these?

Is there a way how to do this, or i need to do it manually in both GA4 properties?

Thanks for any help which saves me manual monkey work.